# Override plugins configuration in poms.xml on a different level

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have maven project and assume it looks like that

```
pom-parent
--pom child1
--pom child2
```

- In pom parent I have defined plugin configuration for `surfire plugin` in default build.
  In pom parent I have defined profile `integration-test` with `surfire plugin` but different configuration.
- In childs pom I override configuration of `surfire plugin` in default build(not in profile section), by adding `combine.self` in configuration tag default build(not in profile section).

My question is if I run `mvn clean install -Pintegration-test` what configuration for `surfire plugin` on each level will be applyied?

- pom parent =>(default or that from profile?) pom
- pom child1 =>(profile
  configuration will be overrited by default childs configuration?)
- pom
  child2 => (same as for child1?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling I got the answer to my question. This **[article](http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/#.U0V88fl%5fs40)** is very helpful to understand how merging in maven wokrs.

Very helpful command **`mvn help:effective-pom`** fired form parent level.

Basically for my question the answer is.

The parent pom will have configuration defined in profile, but when we define in profile configuration for plugin in tag `<pluginManagement>` it will be inherited to all children(even if they do not define their plugin configuration in profile, but they define it in simple `plugin` ->`configuration` space in default `build` tag) and merged with theirs configuration according to above article and strategy that we apply in children's poms.

I home it will someday help somebody with the same issue.